# Is there a Jackson annotation to use a wrapper class during deserialization as well as during serialization for Strings

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

Hi StackOverflow Community,

I am currently trying to deserialize JSON request bodies provided via Spring Boot `@RestController`.

The request body contains the following array:

```
{
  ...
  "productIds": [
    "123abc",
    "234def"
  ],
  ...
}
```

However, I don't want to deserialize the product IDs into a list of Strings, but rather use a simple wrapper class (for various reasons, including but not limited to additional type safety and validation opportunities). Consequently the class looks like this (*Lombok annotations were used to keep the code snippet short*):

```
@Value
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TheRequest {
   ...
   List<ProductId> productIds;
   ...
}
```

with ProductId being just a simple wrapper as already said (validation annotations are omitted for the sake of brevity):

```
@Value
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductId{
   String id;
}
```

Looking at Stackoverflow I only found ways to achieve this using rather verbose custom deserialization methods.
However, I am a bit astonished, that Jackson does not provide this functionality out of the box. Consequently it would be great if anyone has any idea if

- there is a more elegant way to achieve deserialization of a array of Strings into a List of WrapperObjects, ideally only using Jackson annotations?
- there is an elegant way to achieve serialization of such a resulting List of `ProductId` wrapper objects back into String objects, ideally also using only Jackson annotations? I tried Jacksons `@Value` but that did not provide the required result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me still to verbose but it seems to be a working solution with Jacson 2.14+:

```java
public record PayloadId(String id) {

  @JsonCreator(mode = Mode.DELEGATING)
  public PayloadId{}

  @JsonValue
  @Override
  public String id() {
    return id;
  }
}
```

...and here is the records test https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.14/src/test-jdk14/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/records/RecordCreatorsTest.java